# How to get AWS account alias from account ID without credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Given an AWS account ID, I'd like to programmatically retrieve its account alias from an uncredentialed client. Is this possible? If so, how?

If I have credentials for the account, it's straightforward to get the account alias. What I don't know is how to get the alias *without* credentials.

I'm writing a client that retrieves temporary security tokens using the AWS Security Token Service (STS) and SAML. I have a list of AWS account IDs and a list of roles that can be assumed. I'd like to display this information to the user in a friendly way (ie. translate the account IDs to account names), but I don't want to have to assume all the roles to do so.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to get this information without credential. What you can can do is to create a local cache for each account ID and use it to show, instead of the ID.

Comment: If you have roles that can be assumed, you could assume each role in turn and query for the Alias.